# cannot find symbol method add SoapObject(SoapObject)

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2xzS.png)

I am getting such an error rejoice if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this jar file;

```
ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar.jar
```

[Download this jar file by clicking this link and put in libs folder in android studio](https://javalibs.com/artifact/com.google.code.ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly)

Comment: Tried but not.
Is there another way?

Comment: Ok fixed.Thank You